# Getting all json files from folder Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, routes

I'm facing an issue where I can't create a table row for each json file in particular folder. Here is how my code looks like.

**My modul**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ngResource','ngQuickDate']);
```

**My service for getting the json files**

```
myApp.factory('NotesData',function($resource) {
    var resource = $resource('/data/notes/:id',{id:'@id'});

    return {
        getNote: function(id) {
            return resource.get({id: id});
        },
        getAllNotes: function() {
            return resource.query();
        }
    }
});
```

**My controller to list the notes**

```
myApp.controller('NotesController', function NotesController($scope,$routeParams,NotesData) {
    $scope.notes = NotesData.getAllNotes();
});
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? You mention json files, but I don't see what they have to do with your question. I assume /date/notes/ is a REST API?

Comment: if I do a log on $scope.notes it returns an empty array. And when I open my notes list route, I get in my console 'Cannot GET http://localhost:3000/data/notes', which is understandable cause I need to get the json files in that folder, not the folder itself. I'm running my App using GULP browserify, not sure if that might be causing the issues.

Comment: The application can't read all files in that folder. `$resource` is normally used to interact with a REST API. This would be a second application that for example could return a json response. This could of course be as simple as a list in json that contains the path to all your other files.